# Flutter getting string between special characters using RegEx

Tags: dart

I have string like this one `==here==`. How can I get `here` using RegEx pattern.

I know I can use `.substring` like

```dart
    const pattern = "==";
    const str = "==here==";
    final start = str.indexOf(pattern) + pattern.length;
    final end = str.lastIndexOf(pattern);

    final sub = str.substring(start, end);

    expect(sub, 'here');
```

for this but I want to use regex pattern so that I could get first match correctly.

What I want exactly is to get first string that is wrapped in two `==` even if there are thousand matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String find(String str) {
RegExp exp = RegExp(r'==([^]*?)==');
RegExpMatch? match = exp.firstMatch(str);
return match?.group(1) ?? '';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest RegExp just matches `==(something)==` and uses the capture.
Here it uses a non-greedy match so that it finds the first following `==`.

```dart
var re = RegExp(r'==([^]*?)==');
var sub = re.firstMatch(str)?[1];
```

If you *need* the RegExp match itself to be the string between the `==`s, you can use look-behind and look-ahead:

```dart
var re = RegExp(r'(?<===)[^]*?(?===)');
var sub = re.firstMatch(str)?[0];
```